# How to set Frame properly in Viewdidappear using reference of cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to display captured video using `MPMoviePlayer` for that purpose I designed one customcell and number of sections is one and I am loading ten by ten records in `tableView` so number of rows depends on array count so every time ten by ten records displaying from `getService` and my problem is frame is not setting properly in cell for that purpose I wrote entire code in one method and called that method in `viewDidAppear()` and when getting cell reference in `viewDidAppear()` getting fatal error in `NSIndexPath` I am thinking that `viewDidAppear()` is calling before I am getting cell reference so how to solve this problem please tell me any solution?

Comment: Please edit your post to not be **one GIANT run on sentence**. This makes it very difficult to read. Also code examples really help. "Please tell me a solution" without a solid grasp of what you are already doing is not a realistic request.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to manipulate with frames of cells from `viewDidAppear` of your view controller.

A frame consists of: left, top, width, and height.

- **left** is always 0;
- **top** is specified by a table and is based on the index path and heights of previous cells, section headers, and a table's header;
- **width** is always equal to a width of the table;
- **height** you can specify by yourself by overriding `UITableViewDelegate`'s method `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
  heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`

But most likely you are interested in a different thing. And you want to layout UI elements within you cells. If yes, you have a few ways to do this:

- Override `func layoutSubviews()` method in the cell and set all frames you want. This method is called every time when frame is changed. So it's exactly what you need.
- Also you can specify the desired layout using auto layouts. This may be done in a storyboard/xib file or in code (in a designated constructor of the cell).